# Converting malloc() calls into external Library Calls in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am writing an open-source tool for run-time memory issue debugging:

https://github.com/sandeepsinghmails/S_malloc

The current version requires the user to change his/her wrapper functions for `malloc()` and `free()` and call two additional functions from my library.

I want to modify this code so that the user's `malloc()` and `free()` calls are automatically mapped to my own implementations. The user need not modify his source code (something which Valgrind provides).

Can somebody please guide me on this?

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` to the rescue (just Google it).

Comment: Note that Valgrind provides this using a different mechanism: it executes the "client" program on a virtual processor, allowing it to manipulate anything along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at malloc_hooks:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_hook.3.html

The GNU C library lets you modify the behavior of malloc(3), realloc(3),
       and free(3) by specifying appropriate hook functions.  You can use these
       hooks to help you debug programs that use dynamic memory allocation, for
       example.

Comment: Thanks. But I faced another issue with malloc_hook and LD_PRELOAD. My own Tool Code involves malloc & free(). Now, these calls are interefering with the Application's Logs as well. Can you provide some hint on how to disable the wrapper for some selective calls? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. You should use the original hooks directly, from our app. Wrap them in my_malloc, my_calloc and so on, then make a header that redefines malloc to my_malloc , calloc to my_calloc, and include it after the standart headers.